# Unable to get updated attributes and their values from cognito with aws-amplify

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

Unable to get current attributes and their values from Cognito

Here is the complete flow of what I did

1. successfully logged in with  aws-amplify
2. const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
   console.log("cognitoUser", cognitoUser);
3. got the Cognito user attributes info which is all correct (name, sub, email, email_verified)
4. called a backend API to update the user info (added one more attribute "profile": 1)
5. checked from Cognito user pool, it was successfully added and "profile": 1 was there
6. again I did         const cognitoUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
   console.log("cognitoUser", cognitoUser);
7. got the old result again  (name, sub, email, email_verified). "profile": 1 was not there
8. successfully signed out with  aws-amplify
9. logged in again
10. the keys this time got from the console.log are (name, sub, email, email_verified, profile)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

after searching a lot I found the answer.
there is something called bypass cache. this is how we can use it

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify';

Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser({
    bypassCache: false  // Optional, By default is false. If set to true, this call will send a request to Cognito to get the latest user data
}).then(user => console.log(user))
.catch(err => console.log(err));
```